# As3 - this.addChild() when gotoAndStop(), child does not remove

Tags: actionscript-3

This may be a beginner's question. I have been using `this.addChild()` to add MovieClips in `this`.

But as I noticed, the child in `this` doesn't mean it is in the current frame, so I use script to remove the child when I change the current frame. Does that means `this` is the current scene?

I tried `currentFrame.addChild();` but when I read the documentary, `currentFrame` only returns a value.

What can I do to only addChild() to the current frame?**AND NOT USE REMOVECHILD();** or is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've actually worked with the Flash timeline (as oppose to pure Actionscript), but I guess the easiest way would be to create a movieclip on the frame itself in the timeline, then instead of calling `this.addChild()`, call `movieclip.addChild()`. Since the movieclip does not exist in subsequent frames, neither will its child movieclips.

Answer (score 0):

you should addChild(), and when you change frame, removeChild().

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add children to specific frames of a MovieClip using ActionScript at run time - it's only possible to add children to specific frames of a MovieClip in the IDE.

If you wish for these clips to exist only on one frame, you could use event listeners to listen for frame events, and use those to trigger the adding/removal of children.